# Persistence of SCNAudioPlayer on SCNNodes in Xcode Instrument

Tags: ios, swift, instruments, scnnode

I have created a subclass of `SCNNode`. It is made up of few child nodes. 
I have declared a method, viz. `soundCasual()` which adds a `SCNAudioPlayer` to the instance of this class. Everything is working as expected and audio is being played, when this method is called. This method is called on that node whenever that node is *tapped* (gesture).

**Code:**

```
class MyNode: SCNNode {
    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()
    let audioSource5 = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "audiofile.mp3")

    override init() {
        super.init()

        if let virtualScene = SCNScene(named: "MyNode.scn", inDirectory: "Assets.scnassets/Shapes/MyNode") {
            for child in virtualScene.rootNode.childNodes {
                wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
            }
        }
    }

   func soundCasual() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { [weak self] in
            if let audioSource = self?.audioSource5 {
                let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
                self?.wrapperNode.removeAllAudioPlayers()
                self?.wrapperNode.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue within Instruments (Allocations)**

When I analyse my whole codebase (which is several other things), I see that whenever I tap on that node, allocation count of SCNAudioPlayer is increased by one while profiling within Instruments. But all of the increase is **persistent**. By definition of `SCNAudioPlayer`, I assumed that this the player is removed after playback, which is why the increment should be in Transient allocations, but it is not working like this. That is why I tried `removeAllAudioPlayers()` before adding an SCNAudioPlayer to the node, as you can see in the code for `soundCasual()`. But the issue remains.

Till this snapshot was taken, I had tapped on that node about **17** times, and it also shows 17 against Persistent allocations for SCNAudioPlayer.

***Note***: `SCNAudioSource` is 10, as it should be, since there are 10 audio source I am using in the app

[image]

And this is happening for all other SCNNodes in my application without fail. 
Kindly help as I am not able to understand what exactly am I missing.

**EDIT**

As per recommended, I changed my `init()` as

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Keemo", ofType: "scn", inDirectory: "Assets.scnassets/Shapes/Keemo")
if let path = path , let keemo = SCNReferenceNode(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
    keemo.load()
}
func soundPlay() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { [weak self] in
        if let audioSource = self?.audioSourcePlay {
            audioSource.volume = 0.1
            let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
            self?.removeAllAudioPlayers()
            self?.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)
        }
    }
}
```

Despite, allocations in Instruments show audioPlayers as persistent. Though on checking `node.audioPlayers` it shows that at one point, there is only one audioPlayer node attached.

**EDIT**

This issue appears even in a simple case when I use the boilerplate codebase attached in a Scenekit app created by default in XCode. Hence, this issue has been raised as a bug to Apple. https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=43482539

**WORKAROUND**

I am using AVAudioPlayer instead of SCNAudioPlayer, not exactly the same thing, but at least memory this way will not cause a crash.

Comment: Can you please show the code for your removeAllAudioPlayers()

Comment: Apologies, that’s a simple instance method, please see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1523570-removeallaudioplayers

Comment: Otherwise, it is simply ‘let myNode = MyNode()’; ‘myNode.soundCasual()’; ‘myNode.removeAllAudioPlayers()’

Comment: @Manganese what is the output of [`.audioPlayers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1523244-audioplayers) ?

Comment: @StephenFurlani empty Array [], because that's what is supposed to happen. AudioNodes once played, are removed technically. But then yes, if audioNodes are being added to wrapperNode, whereas I am checking self, might be an issue in my answer here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with SceneKit, but from my experience with UIKit and SpriteKit I suspect that your use of `wrapperNode` and `virtualScene` is messing with the garbage collector.

I would try removing `wrapperNode` and adding everything to `self` (since `self` is a `SCNNode`).

Which node is being used in your scene? `self` or `wrapperNode`? And with your sample code `wrapperNode` is not added to `self` so it may or may not actually be part of the scene.

Also, you should probably be using [`SCNReferenceNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnreferencenode) instead of the virtual scene thing you're using.

!!! this code has not been tested !!!

```
class MyNode: SCNReferenceNode {
    let audioSource5 = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "audiofile.mp3")

    func soundCasual() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { [weak self] in
            if let audioSource = self?.audioSource5 {
                let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
                self?.removeAllAudioPlayers()
                self?.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)
            }
        }
    }
}


// If you programmatically create this node, you'll have to call .load() on it
let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(URL: referenceURL)
referenceNode.load()
```

HtH!

Comment: Sounds interesting to me. Let me make all changes as per suggested and I will update you. Since I am commuting, might take a few days. Apologies.

Comment: Yes, the distinction between wrapper and self sounds like it might be an issue.

Comment: I am intrigued by the point you are making about the usage of `SCNReferenceNode` vs. a usual `SCNNode`. Would the former be more efficient or better in some respect?

Comment: @Manganese the `SCNReferenceNode` automatically loads a scene file and is the _sanctioned_ way from Apple to load nodes from a scene file. I suspect that Apple is doing something to optimize the garbage collection of the `SCNNode` and since you've created this separate scene it might not be part of it.

Comment: I change the structure as per your recommendation. Have added it as an edit. Still no truck.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Apple has accepted this as a bug as per my communications with them. I will keep posted on the workaround as they've mentioned they will suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found the answer already, you need to remove the SCNAudioPlayer from the node once it has completed playing:

```
if let audioSource = self?.audioSourcePlay {
    audioSource.volume = 0.1
    let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
    self?.removeAllAudioPlayers()
    self?.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)
    self?.audioplayer.didFinishPlayback = {
        self?.removeAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, I think I tried this already. Let me check it once more and I will come back. Apologies that I missed your post. Thanks.